# In Scala, why can’t I use a context bound for type constructors?

Tags: scala, manifest, higher-kinded-types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Context bounds shortcut with higher kinded-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541154/context-bounds-shortcut-with-higher-kinded-types)

Why doesn't the Scala compiler let me write this?

```
class TypeCtor[M[_]: ClassManifest]
```

It complains with “error: type M takes type parameters”. If I'm only asking for the `ClassManifest`, the compiler should be able to insert it no matter what the parametrization of `M` is, no?

This works as expected:

```
class TypeCtor[M[_]](implicit val ev: ClassManifest[M[_]])
(new TypeCtor[Vector]).ev.erasure // => class scala.collection.immutable.Vector
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541154/context-bounds-shortcut-with-higher-kinded-types).

Comment: Great, thanks, I'd missed that one. I've voted to close my question as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The parameterization of M is indeeed irrelevant, but the Scala compiler needs a parameter for ClassManifest in order to know *which* manifest to insert. Let's say we have

```
class TypeCtor[A,B](implicit val ev: ClassManifest)
```

Now the Compiler would not know whether to insert the Manifest of A or B. Also you can't write ClassManifest[M] because ClassManifest expects a Type of kind * and M has kind * -> *.

Comment: Thanks! But I still don't understand why one variant works (with the written-out implicit val) and the other doesn't (with the context bound).

Comment: Oh! I just realized I misunderstood your question...